# shortest Clojure static typing

Tags: clojure, static-typing

what is the literal simplest, shortest way to typecheck a clojure function. The regular ann form is pretty short:

```
(ann bar [Number -> Number])
(defn bar [b]
  (+ 2 (foo b)))
```

But can we (with a macro or something) make it look smaller, like:

```
(defn bar [b : Number -> Number]
  (+ 2 (foo b)))
```

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You might want to reconsider whether "shortest, simplest" is really the metric you want: IMO it's never the right metric for anything. What do you want from your static-typing system? If there is a feature missing from one system, but it's shorter than an alternative that has it, which would you choose?

Comment: I maybe miss the point of the question. Are you asking for what syntax Clojurists would prefer, if that where a thing (e.g. you are you doing a popularity poll for something you are working on)? Or are you asking what libraries etc. you can use to get static type checks like you provided examples for?

Comment: I understand you are looking to type check, but generally speaking that is not idiomatic Clojure. I suggest considering Spec if it solves your problem. https://clojure.org/guides/spec and the rationale https://clojure.org/about/spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) is the best.  See also [this blog post](http://plumatic.github.io/schema-for-clojurescript-data-shape-declaration-and-validation).

Here is an example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [schema.core :as s]))

(s/defn add2 :- s/Num ; "superclass" for any number
  [a :- s/Int ; must be an integer type
   b :- Double] ; Must be a java.lang.Double
  (+ a b))

(dotest
  (throws? (add2 1 2))
  (throws? (add2 1.0 2))
  (is= 3.0 (add2 1 2.0)))
```

[I also have some predefined "types"](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/20.07.28/api/tupelo.schema) in addition to the basic ones.  For example, `tupelo.schema/Keymap` is any map with keyword keys.  `Pair` is any vector or sequence of length=2, etc.

---

### Update

Please also see [my Clojure template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  In particular,
the file `test/clj/_bootstrap.clj` exists for the sole purpose of enabling Plumatic Schema type checks when you type `lein test` (they are disabled by default, so there is no cost in production).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is spec checking and not static typing, but you may want to check out [Guardrails](https://github.com/fulcrologic/guardrails) (a fork of [Ghostwheel](https://github.com/gnl/ghostwheel), which is unmaintained) which aims to tackle some of the problems static typing does and more:

```clj
(>defn ranged-rand
   [start end]
   [int? int? | #(< start end)
    => int? | #(>= % start) #(< % end)]
   (+ start (long (rand (- end start)))))
```